# PDF File Splitter

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-editor

What I need is a simple PDF File Splitter. I want to be able to:

1. Take a PDF File (Let's say 20 pages)
2. Choose what pages to delete
3. Create a new PDF with the rest of the pages

I would prefer a free software for windows

Comment: http://www.sejda.com/ may help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A PDF splitter is a piece of software that takes a PDF file as input and outputs more PDF files that contain only a set of pages or a single page.

For this you could use **[PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/)**.

- free and open-source
- platform independent (Java based)
- splits PDF files
- merges PDF files

[image]

You can then merge only specific PDF files (the pages that you want).

Answer (score 12):

I have had a lot of success using [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) it comes in 3 versions, *(Free GUI, [Server/Command Line](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) and Pro GUI)* has the following features:

- GUI Interface *("Free" & "Pro") but both versions include the command line "Server" version*
- Command Line/Server Interface *(included in installation of both GUI versions)*
- Make a pdf from specific pages of an existing pdf *(all versions)*
- Make a single pdf from specific or all pages of several pdfs *(all versions)*
- XP, Vista, Win7, Win8 *(GUI versions)*
- Win/Mac OSX/Linux *(Command Line/Server)*
- Encrypt/Decrypt pdfs *(Pro GUI & Free Command Line/Server)*
- Rotate page(s) *(Pro GUI & Free Command Line/Server)*
- Handle Forms *(Pro GUI & Free Command Line/Server)*
- Watermarks *(Pro GUI & Free Command Line/Server)*
- **Free!** *except the Pro Version which at $3.99 is more than reasonably priced.*
- Commercial Support for the Server Version is available *(currently $79/pa)*.
- The command line/server edition is also available as source code.

[image: pdftk GUI]

Comment: Note that the options: "Encrypt/Decrypt", "Rotate page(s)" and "Watermarks" are not available in the FREE version.

Comment: @MrWhite while the Free GUI version does not include those facilities the command line, server, version does and is also free, (editing the answer to make this clearer).

Comment: Ah ok, that’s great, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a copy of a PDF file without certain pages using a virtual PDF printer like **[doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com)**.

- free
- runs on Windows
- no adware

Open the PDF in your favorite viewer and print it to doPDF. The page selection dialog will differ based on your PDF viewer.

[image]

You select a single page by its number or an interval by limits (10-20). Pages and intervals are separated by commas.

Comment: This feature is also built-in to Google Chrome web browser. Go to print, select "Save as PDF" as the destination and choose your pages.

Answer (score 5):

The non-free solution is [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com). Not Adobe Reader.

Open a PDF file, open the `Tools` pane from the right, `Pages` category and select `Delete Pages`. Enter page range and click `Delete`.

[image]

Save the PDF with <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

The best one I have found is the PDFmod. It is free and easy to use. It is slow but it's so easy to use and works for anything I need. You can even combine PDF files. You can find it in the software manager. I went to the web page, but it's not working. If you have Linux Mint or Ubuntu it's in the software manager.

[Here is a link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pdfmod/.) to the Ubuntu page maybe that will help.

Ok after some more looking around here is the link for the free windows version of the PDF Mode [I hope this helps](http://alternativeto.net/software/pdf-mod/?license=opensource&platform=windows)

Comment: Can you add a link for download?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above answers –
**you can achieve the result only using PDF printer (if you already have it).**

In case if you do not have any of special tools (and do not want to install them) , and your PDF is only plain one (without hyperlinks, forms, etc.) then you can simply use your PDF viewer (e.g. [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/)) with PDF printer (e.g. [PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/)) this way:
**From your PDF viewer, print selected PDF page range to PDF printer.**

In PDF viewer, print the PDF like this:
[image]

**Note:** before printing, check PDF printer settings in order to preserve image resolution and other document quality aspects.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to use free [Dysprosium](http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Downloads.html#part2) software for splitting PDF documents.

1. It comes as a portable JAR executable.
2. It is free and small for download.
3. Hence, no need to install. Double click on it to run.
4. You can separate the document into equal parts, for example split all pages.
   [image]
5. You can split into desired parts
   [image]
   [image]
6. It honours bookmarks.
   [image]
7. Put it in the bin if you do not need it. No need to un-install.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wondershare PDF Converter for Windows](http://guidechart.com/wondershare-pdf-converter/) - it can split and merge PDF, convert them and more.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/107) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it will be removed. See also the other answers on this question for ideas of improvements.

Answer (score 0):

PdfCpu works great:

```
pdfcpu collect -p 2-3 in.pdf out.pdf
```

https://pdfcpu.io/core/collect

Answer (score -1):

Based on your requirements and the output that you wish to attain, I think what you need is software that can delete pages instead of splitting them. When you split PDF pages, you actually create two or more kinds of PDF as the effect of the split. When you delete pages, you remove the unwanted pages from the PDF document and save the remaining pages as a new file. I recommend you try using one of the tools we developed at [DeftPDF.com](https://deftpdf.com/delete-pdf-pages), which is the delete PDF pages tool. This tool can precisely answer to your needs by simply going to the site, uploading your file, deleting the pages from the thumbnail and downloading the new file. Here is how it looks like when you are using the tool.
[image]

However, if you do not wish to use online tools and being online to split or delete the pages in your PDF, another option is to extract the preferred pages out of the PDF by using the *print to PDF* feature which is readily available in most computers and built-in applications. To do this, just open the file, select print but before you continue to printing, change the printer to "print to PDF" and encode which pages you will "print" - which are those pages you want to keep. This will extract the file out of your PDF and make a new PDF once the print button is clicked.
[image]

Disclosure: We're the developers of DeftPDF online software. We created this online web-based program to help people like you with PDF problems and we would like to suggest that you try our free software online. I hope this solves your document requirements and if there are any questions about this suggestion, please feel free to send me a message.

Comment: Please add a clear disclose revealing your affiliation with this product.  Thanks!